# Issue with default credentials error GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

> DefaultCredentialsError: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for more information.

I get this error whenever I am trying to do thing using GCP API. I have already done

```
gcloud authh application-default login
```

but I still have this issue.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use `gcloud auth login` in place of `gcloud authh application-default login`

anyway-

meanwhile better to understand the difference between [gcloud CLI credentials and ADC credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/gcloud#gcloud-credentials)

> **gcloud CLI credentials and ADC credentials**
>
> When you sign in to the
> gcloud CLI, you use the gcloud auth login command to provide your user
> credentials, which the gcloud CLI uses for authentication and
> authorization to manage Google Cloud resources and services. These
> credentials are your gcloud CLI credentials.
>
> When you use the gcloud CLI to provide credentials to ADC, you use the
> gcloud auth application-default login command. This command puts your
> credentials into a well-known location for use by ADC in your local
> environment. These are your local ADC credentials.
>
> Your local ADC credentials and your gcloud CLI credentials are two
> distinct sets of credentials. The gcloud CLI does not use ADC to
> obtain credentials.

**Command   Description:**

`gcloud auth login`

> Generates user credentials that are used to authenticate to and authorize access to Google Cloud
> services.

`gcloud auth application-default login`

> Generates user credentials that
> are provided to Application Default Credentials for use in a local
> development environment.